# Java beginner here, separating my client class into multiple methods?

Tags: java, sockets, client

Ok so basically I'm creating an online multiplayer tic tac toe game using sockets but I've run into some logic trouble in my client class. I need to have the client running but then be able to write and read in a separate method from where the socket, streams, etc are. I'm sure this is a very simple solution and I'm probably over thinking it, I've googled it and I just can't seem to wrap my brain around it. 
Basically my final structure should be

```
public Client
{
Instantiate sockets/streams, etc here.
}
public void writeAndRead
{
Write and read here.
}
```

My current problem is I cannot call my writer from another method. 
My code is as follows

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Client
{
private String host;
private int port;
public Client(String host2, int port2) throws IOException
{
host = host2;
port = port2;
    //Instantiate a stringbuffer to store the reply from the server.
    StringBuffer instr = new StringBuffer();

    //Stores the host string into a usable IP.
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);

    //Instantiate a socket with the given IP and port name.
    Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);

    //Instantiate a output stream to the socket.
    BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    //Instantiate a writer for the output stream using standard encoding.
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "US-ASCII");

    //Instantiate an input stream to read in reply from server.
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    //Instantiate a reader to read and convert the stream, once again using standard encoding.
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "US-ASCII"); 

        //Create the string to send to server with a char to let the stream reader know when     the stream is completed.
        String process = "x" + (char) 0;

        //Write the string to the output stream.
        writer.write(process);

        //Clear the output stream.
        writer.flush();

        //Int c reads the data from the input stream.
        int c;

        //Receive the message and print.
        while ( (c = reader.read()) != 0)
        instr.append( (char) c);

            System.out.println("Message received from server: " + instr);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do is read the input stream from the socket on a separate Thread so you can read and write the same time without waiting for packets of information to be delivered first. For the writing to the socket you can put the in the Main Thread.

Answer (score 0):

In a class it is usually a good idea to have some variables as private fields in you class and that your constructor is responsible the initial collection of and initialization of these variables.

So as you have

```
public Client(String host, int port) throws IOException
{
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}
```

and then other methods will do one piece of work

e.g.

```
public void connect () {

   //Stores the host string into a usable IP.
   InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);

   //Instantiate a socket with the given IP and port name.
   this.socket = new Socket(address, port);  // yes another field

}
```

and then other methods will do the reading and writing.

Also you may  find that you need to use separate Threads, so try following a Chat example which you can easily find on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the variable `writer` should be a class variable instead of in the scope of the constructor for Client:

```
public class Client {
    private OutputStreamWriter writer;
    private String host;
    private int port;

    public Client(String host2, int port2) throws IOException
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void readAndWrite() {
        // ...
        writer.write();
    }
}
```